# API Token & Team Token for Testflight

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I need API Token and Team Token of testflight for uploading app to testflight via jenkins. Some of the links referenced to go https://testflightapp.com and fetch tokens from here. But, it's not responding.

So, How can I get API Token and Team Token of testflight. Please any one help me to find out the tokens.

Thank you in advance...!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `altool` to validate and upload your release to the App Store:

```
$ altool --validate-app -f file -t platform -u username [-p password] [--output-format xml]
$ altool --upload-app -f file -t platform -u username [-p password] [--output-format xml]
```

More information in [Apple's Documentation](https://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/#/apdATD1E53-D1E1A1303-D1E53A1126)